# How to choose particular version of JRE from buildpack

Tags: buildpack, pcf

Am new to PCF and using Java buildpack version 4.48.2 in my app which offers multiple OpenJDK JRE version like 11 and 17.

How can I enable Java17 when deploying my app? Am getting `UnsupportedClassVersionError` - appears its picking up the default version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the environment variable as given below to enable Java17

```
cf set-env app_name JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE '{ jre: { version: 17.+ } }'
```